# Can not dismiss notification of service created

Tags: android, android-studio, service, notifications

I've created a service , And I also created a notification so when my service runs there is a notification for it.
Now , I want users to be able to swipe/dismiss the notification but when trying to do so I've encountered two problems:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        number = intent.getStringExtra("number");


    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =   PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).
            setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name)).
            setContentText("Subject").
            setContentInfo("Doing stuff in the background...").
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic).
            setAutoCancel(true).
            setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(1, notification);


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

This code worked perfectly , the only problem with this code is that users cannot swipe dismiss the notification , So from searching around I found that I can fix it by replacing 'startForeground' function with

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
```

And then it worked, I can swipe dismiss, But now I get a different problem , Once I close my application (using long press on middle button then close all applications)
My app thrrows a nullpointerexception few moments later pointing to the line :

```
  password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
```

as if the intent is null. This does not happen when I use the startForeground function

What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options to what should happen once the proccess in which the service is running on crushes:
START_STICKY , START_NOT_STICKY , START_REDELIVER_INTENT.
I wanted to reload the service and keep the intent once it crushes.
START_REDELIVER_INTENT did the trick, it restarts the service and redelivers the intent.
START_STICKY , Almost did the trick , the problem with START_STICKY for me was that it restarts the service but with a null intent.

Comment: You are right but you didn't mention in your question that you want to restrart your service so that's why i suggested the START_NOT_STICKY solution.

Comment: You are right , sorry for that , I did seem to not mention it.

Comment: what do you mean by "process in which the service is running on crushes" ??  Why will the service crash ??  Do you mean Android OS killing the service due to shortfall of resources ??

Answer (score 1):

Return START_NOT_STICKY  in onStartCommand().

Answer (score 1):

AutoCancel does not work when service is still on foreground. Try remove service from foreground first:

```
startForeground(1, notification);
stopForeground(false); //false - do not remove generated notification
```